# Using Linux ioctl with Mono

Tags: mono, ioctl

I'm trying to do ioctl command through Mono framework, but I cant find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to send command to a DVB card that has a kernel module. I hope someone can link or explain clearly how this can be done. Any example with Mono using kernel modules would be useful I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono does not contain a wrapper for ioctl in Mono.Unix, because ioctl call parameters vary greatly and such a wrapper would be almost useless. You should declare a [DllImport](http://mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) for each ioctl you need.

You probably don't need a helper library written in C, however, you may need it during development to extract actual values hidden behind different C preprocessor macros. For example, to expand C header:

```
#define FE_GET_INFO                _IOR('o', 61, struct dvb_frontend_info)
```

compile and execute this helper:

```
#include <linux/dvb/frontend.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("const int FE_GET_INFO = %d;\n", FE_GET_INFO);
  return 0;
}
```

[A short mono mailing list discussion on the topic](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2006-July/032069.html).

Answer (score 2):

ioctl isn't supported by Mono AFAIK. Too OS-specific and parameter list depends on actual request. You could try DLLImport

[Interop with Native Libraries](http://mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries)

Answer (score 2):

You should write a wrapper library for your exact calls. Look at how Mono.Unix wraps syscalls (google codesearch for Mono.Unix Syscall.cs) to get the idea. Then create a wrapper for each specific ioctl command, which uses your own representation of the data.

As jitter said - you'll need to DLLImport the ioctl itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check for my [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387603/p-invoke-ioctl-system-call), and later question on the [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972740/c-sharp-union-structure-marshalling). In this case I'm trying to wrap the Videl4Linux interface, that could be of interest for you.

I really suggest those readings.